# minimal socket server written in python for openshift

Tags: python, sockets, tornado, openshift

I would like to create a minimal socket server written in python that I can run with my OpenShift account. I searched more than a day, found lots of libraries(tornado, django, twisted, flask, autobahn, gevent) that could be used for this, but I could not manage to implement it for me. (Actually I do not really know the differences between these.)
I looked for lots of tutorials as well, I found an implementation using Tornado:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.template

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    loader = tornado.template.Loader(".")
    self.write('hello world')

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
  def open(self):
    print 'connection opened...'
    self.write_message("The server says: 'Hello'. Connection was accepted.")

  def on_message(self, message):
    self.write_message("The server says: " + message + " back at you")
    print 'received:', message

  def on_close(self):
    print 'connection closed...'

application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r'/ws', WSHandler),
  (r'/', MainHandler),
  (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./resources"}),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  application.listen(8000)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

However I cannot connect to it from a simple html5 websocket client, furthermore I get `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` when I enter my domain.

Could you please either give me a minimal implementation (if possible using tornado, or maybe django) that works if upload it to OpenShift or link me a trustworthy and 100% reliable tutorial? I would be really pleased I can't get my head around this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use port address on openshift like that, I suggest you to do this:

```
   ip   = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
   port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
   application.listen(port , ip)
   tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Check this repo for example: https://github.com/avinassh/openshift-tornado-starter

Comment: Have you tried it with scaling Mode? i am going to test it now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like OpenShift lets you just run an application like that. You can see a howto guide here: https://github.com/giulivo/openshift-hellotornado

Comment: does it mean that I cannot do socketing on openshift? This guide is about how to deploy tornado, but that can be done thru the GUI as well... 
> Is it possible to do it with any of the mentioned libraries?

Comment: No, it seems you can: https://www.openshift.com/tags/websockets. But you would need to start your tornado server in the way they suggest. Not by directly running it and listening on port 8000.

Comment: I just found that you work on pythoneverywhere... I planned to try my project there too, do you have socketing compatibilites?

Comment: Correct, just have tornado listen on 8080 to the OPENSHIFT_IP_ADDR ( can't quite remember the env. variable) and then send your socket requests to port 8000 from the external url

Comment: No, not yet. Or I would have suggested us :)